# Printing List Information

Tags: python

I am working my way through some practice material and I have come across some syntax that doesn't make scene to me, this is how i interpreted the value in the list and the position within the list.

```
info = [ 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 9, 12, 4 ]

         0  1  2  3  4  5   6  7
```

For example;

code:

```
print(info[1])
```

result:

```
6
```

Because the value six in the list is in position one correct ?.

### **My Question**

**code:**

```
print(info[info[4]])
```

**Returns:**

```
9
```

Why is this ?

Comment: Ok I see now, because the value inside the [] is processed first.

Comment: Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `info[4]` is `5`, `info[info[4]]` is just `info[5]`, which is the sixth element (`9`).

Answer (score 3):

`info[info[4]]` first looks at the value of `info[4]`, which is `5`.  This gives you `info[5]`, and the value of this is `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember from inside to outside, last in first out or LIFO.

Also i find this visual representation quite helpful.

```
index:
      ------------>
  0   1   2   3   4
+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+
  0  -4  -3  -2  -1
      <------------

slice:
    <---------------|
|--------------->   
:   1   2   3   4   :
+---+---+---+---+---+
| a | b | c | d | e |
+---+---+---+---+---+
:  -4  -3  -2  -1   :
|--------------->   
    <---------------|
```

Comment: A cool thanks for posting even though the correct answer has been awarded, vote up for you :D